# Class construktion: Save and write data

Tags: python

I need to save file and write into a class.I have some problems.

1. when the file is saved I got always error what I don't will. I would like exception only wenn necesarry and in that case delete the saved file.
2. With my code i can't write to text file.What could be a problem with my function SaveFile and Run in class  ?

```
class InterfaceApp(root):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        root.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):

        frInstrument = Tkinter.Frame(width=800, height=200, bg="",colormap="new")
        frInstrument.grid(row=0,sticky='EW')

        # Create a custom Menu
        menu = Tkinter.Menu(self,tearoff = 0)
        self.config(menu=menu)
        filemenu = Tkinter.Menu(self,tearoff = 0)
        menu.add_cascade(label='File',menu=filemenu)
        filemenu.add_command(label='Create New File...', command = self.SaveFile())


    def SaveFile(self):
        self.dataname = asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension='.txt')
        self.datamode = "a"
        try:
            self.fout = open(self.dataname, self.datamode)
        except Exception, e:
            tkMessageBox.showerror("Error", str(e))

    def Run(self):
        self.keithleyPower = rm.open_resource(self.choiceVarPower.get())
        self.keithleyMultimeter = rm.open_resource(self.choiceVarMulti.get())

        self.t = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.currdatetime = self.t.timetuple()
        self.currutime = time.mktime(self.t.timetuple())
        self.yr = str(self.currdatetime[0])
        self.curr_date = "%02d"%int(self.yr[2:]) + "%02d"%self.currdatetime[1] + "%02d"%self.currdatetime[2]
        self.curr_time = "%02d:"%self.currdatetime[3] + "%02d:"%self.currdatetime[4] + "%02d:"%self.currdatetime[5]
        self.date_time = self.curr_date + " " + self.curr_time
        self.fout.write(self.date_time+"\n")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = InterfaceApp(None)
    app.title("LED Monitoring: Voltage rise detection")
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you perhaps only give us the relevant two functions instead of your entire code base? (unless all of your code is the problem ofc)

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `SaveFile` must be repaired.

```
def SaveFile(self):
        self.file_opt = self.options = {}
        self.options['filetypes'] = [('Text Files', '.txt')]
        self.dataname = asksaveasfilename(**self.file_opt)
        self.datamode = 'a'
        try:
            self.fout = open(self.dataname, self.datamode)
        except Exception, e:
            strError = "Output file open error: "+ str(e)
            tkMessageBox.showerror("Error", strError)
```

and you can write the data into a file.

```
self.fout.write("data")
```